# Powershell environment vars

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use an environment var in PowerShell but the examples I've found don't seem to work. This is the script I'm using for testing:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
Write-Host "************" 
$AlarmDatastore = Get-ChildItem Env:*VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME*
Write-Host "Var = " $AlarmDatastore.value
$Test = $env:VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME
Write-Host "Test = " $Test
```

The output of the script:

```
USERNAME                       ADMIN.GABRI
USERPROFILE                    C:\Users\admin.gabri
VMWARE_ALARM_ALARMVALUE        Current values for metric/state
VMWARE_ALARM_DECLARINGSUMMARY  ([Yellow metric Is above 10; Red metric Is a...
VMWARE_ALARM_EVENTDESCRIPTION  Alarm 'Alarm 10 percent test with script' on ...
VMWARE_ALARM_ID                alarm-601
VMWARE_ALARM_NAME              Alarm 10 percent test with script
VMWARE_ALARM_NEWSTATUS         Red
VMWARE_ALARM_OLDSTATUS         Gray
VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_ID         datastore-12587
VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME       VCD-VMFS-095-FAST-VNX-5400-04
VMWARE_ALARM_TRIGGERINGSUMM... Metric Disk Space actually used = 96
windir                         C:\Windows
************
Var =  VCD-VMFS-095-FAST-VNX-5400-04
Test =
```

How come I can only get the environment var using: Get-ChildItem Env:`*`VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME`*`, and not simply by $Test = $env:VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME

Comment: Why are you using wildcards with gci? Why not just use `Get-Item Env:\VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME`? I wonder if maybe there is something the wildcard is catching in the gci call that is not being included when you use `$env`?

Comment: I changed the code to your suggestion and this is the result.
Code:
`$Test2 = Get-Item Env:\VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME
Write-Host "Test2 = " $Test2`
Result:
Get-Item : Cannot find path 'Env:\VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME' because it does not exist.
At G:\DataStoreAlarms\Scripts\EnvTest.ps1:5 char:10
+ $Test2 = Get-Item Env:\VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo        : ObjectNotFound: Env:\VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand

Comment: How about: `gi env:*VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME* | fl *`?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?  I can't repro this on V4.

Comment: This code:
$Test2 = gi env:*VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME*
Write-Host "Test2 = " $Test2.value

Gives:
VCD-VMFS-090  (Which is correct).

Question remains, why do I need those asterisk around it?

Comment: $PSVersionTable.PSVersion = 3.0

Comment: Try this: `[Regex]::Escape((gi env:*VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME*).Value)`. That should help to figure out if there are special characters in there by escaping them (it's regex centric which isn't your use case but it does often help to find strange things that don't print normally). It will also escape spaces so if you see the variable ending with a single `\` it might means there's a space on the end.

Comment: Interesting. You could have whitespace at end of the env var name.  Try this experiment `ls env:*VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME* | % {"'$($_.Name)'"}`

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

```
#Use ${ } for complex variable names
${env:VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME} 

#Or as part of a print statement use env directly (with or without ${env:}):
Write-Host "Test = $($env:VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME)" 

#At an interactive prompt see if it can be tab completed
$env:VMWWARE  #then tab to see if it shows up in auto complete
```

Also it is worth seeing what cmd.exe shows when you run set. In Powershell type:

```
cmd
set
exit
```

and see what the output looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Because of time pressure I had to go with this right now:

```
$AlarmTARGET_NAME = get-childitem Env:*VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME*
$AlarmNAME = get-childitem Env:*VMWARE_ALARM_NAME*
$AlarmEVENTDESCRIPTION = get-childitem Env:*VMWARE_ALARM_EVENTDESCRIPTION*
$AlarmDECLARINGSUMMARY = get-childitem Env:*VMWARE_ALARM_DECLARINGSUMMARY*
$AlarmVALUE = get-childitem Env:*VMWARE_ALARM_ALARMVALUE*
```

Not very clean code, but it works. 
Thanks for all the replies.

Gabrie